# error: wholeNumber is not abstract and does not override abstract method add(int,int) in number class wholeNumber implements number{

Tags: java, interface

i am trying to make an interface for a whole number and a natural number but i am not able to make it can anyone tell me what i am getting the error
alp1.java:9: error: wholeNumber is not abstract and does not override abstract method add(int,int) in number
class wholeNumber implements number{
^
alp1.java:40: error: naturalNumber is not abstract and does not override abstract method add(int,int) in number
class naturalNumber implements number{

```
 interface number{
public void validateNumber(int num);
public void add(int num1,int num2);
public void subtract(int num1,int num2);
public void multiply(int num1,int num2);
public void divide(int num1,int num2);
}

class wholeNumber implements number{
public void validateNumber(int num){
    if(num<-46340 || num>46340){
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }
}

public void sum(int n1,int n2){
    int sum=n1+n2;
    System.out.println("SUM "+sum);
}
public void subtract(int n1,int n2){
    int ans=n1-n2;
    System.out.println("subtract "+ans);
}
public void multiply(int n1,int n2){
    int ans=n1*n2;
    System.out.println("multiply "+ans);
}
public void divide(int n1,int n2){
    if(n2==0){
        System.out.println("divide 0");
    }
    else{
        int ans=n1/n2;
        System.out.println("divide "+ans);
    }
    
}
 }

  class naturalNumber implements number{
public void validateNumber(int num){
    if(num<0|| num>46340){
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }
}

public void sum(int n1,int n2){
    int sum=n1+n2;
    System.out.println("SUM "+sum);
}
public void subtract(int n1,int n2){
    int ans=n1-n2;
    System.out.println("subtract "+ans);
}
public void multiply(int n1,int n2){
    int ans=n1*n2;
    System.out.println("multiply "+ans);
}
public void divide(int n1,int n2){
    if(n2==0){
        System.out.println("divide 0");
    }
    else{
        int ans=n1/n2;
        System.out.println("divide "+ans);
    }
    
}
 }

class alp1{

public static void main(String []args){
    // if(args[0]=="whole"){
    //  wholeNumber obj=new wholeNumber();

    // }
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)
        {System.out.println(args[i]);}
}
}
```

Comment: You have forgot to implement `add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide implementation of add abstract method defined in Number interface.
"java:9: error: **wholeNumber** is not abstract and does not override abstract method **add(int,int)**"

---

Notes on Interfaces:

- It cannot be used to create objects (in the example above, it is not possible to create an "Animal" object in the MyMainClass)
- Interface methods does not have a body - the body is provided by the "implement" class
- On implementation of an interface, you must override all of its methods
- Interface methods are by default abstract and public
- Interface attributes are by default public, static and final
- An interface cannot contain a constructor (as it cannot be used to create objects)

Reference:

-https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_implements.asp#:~:text=The%20implements%20keyword%20is%20used,keyword%20(instead%20of%20extends%20).

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interfaces-in-java/

Comment: Answer is good, but it might help to point the asker to supporting documentation about implementing abstract methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a function `public void add(int num1,int num2);` `add` in the interface, but you have not implemented it in the classes, or rather named it wrongly `public void sum`. Either declare the function as `sum` in the interface or update the name in classes to `add`.